# How to add a condition to the following replace?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace all straight double quotes with curly double quotes:

```js
const text = `"This has an opening and a closing quote."

"This only has an opening quotes

This doesn't have quotes.`

const result = text.replace(/"([^"\n\r]*)"?/g, '&ldquo;$1&rdquo;')

console.log(result)
```

The problem with my current `.replace` is that it's adding curly double quotes when there aren't closing straight double quotes:

> “This has an opening and a closing quote.”
>
> **“This only has an opening quotes”**
>
> This doesn't have quotes.

How to change my `.replace` function so it doesn't add curly double closing quotes when there are no straight double closing quotes?

Expected output:

> “This has an opening and a closing quote.”
>
> “This only has an opening quotes
>
> This doesn't have quotes.

Comment: Why do you have `"?` instead of just `"` for closing quote

Comment: @anubhava If you remove the `?`, the second line won't be replaced: `"This only has an opening quotes`

Comment: But that is what you want right i.e. adding curly double quotes when there is a closing straight double quote? What is your expected output?

Comment: @anubhava I added the expected output to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this code with 2 `.replace` method calls:

1. First we match pair of straight quotes and replace with curly double quotes (html entities).
2. In second `.replace` we just match single `"` and replace with left curly double quote (html entities).

This assumes that single `"` after quoted pair replacement are opening ones.

**Code:**

```js
const text = `"This has an opening and a closing quote."

"This only has an opening quotes

This doesn't have quotes.`;

const result = text.replace(/"([^"\n\r]*)"/g, '&ldquo;$1&rdquo;').replace(/"/g, '&ldquo;');

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Unicode rather than the HTML entities. Like so:

```
const text = `"This has an opening and a closing quote."

"This only has an opening quotes

This doesn't have quotes.`

const result = text.replace(/"([^"\n\r]*)"?/g, '\u201d$1\u201c')

console.log(result)
```

Where `\u201d` is the opening curly quotes and `\u201c` is the closing curly quotes.